# Moving from .NET 4.5 to OWIN .NET 4.6.1, HttpConfiguration not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, .net-4.6.1

I'm refactoring my .NET WebAPI project, moving from .NET 4.5 to the newest 4.6.1.

Everything seems to go smoothly apart from `HttpConfiguration()` which cannot be resolved anymore:

```
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found
```

What's the equivalent class in .NET 4.6.1?

I'm avoiding on purpose to use `System.Web`

My goal is to use OWIN as a replacement for System.Web so I need to find out the OWIN equivalent of `HttpConfiguration`

**EDIT**

This is the code, `HttpConfiguration` is not resolved if I remove every references to `System.Web`

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            using (var configuration = new HttpConfiguration())
            {
                var container = UnityConfig.Container;

                // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(container);
                var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

                configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

                configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
                configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

                app.UseWebApi(configuration);
            }

            app.UseNancy();
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `using System.Web.Http;` You need to add reference to  `System.Web.Http` version 5.2.3.0.

Comment: You'll need `System.Web` as it lives in `System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration`, unless you just fully qualify in the code to avoid a `using` statement?

Comment: @christiandev the requirement is not to use System.Web altogether

Comment: Can you show your code where this is breaking down?

Comment: thanks @christiandev, check my edit on the question itself

Comment: Is using System.Web unavoidable? Is using System.Web.Http an acceptable trade-off? How much unwanted stuff I'm going to bring in if I include System.Web.Http?

Comment: @StephenBrickner uhm.. I've stripped out some other stuff from the HttpConfiguration initializer. If you want I can show you the complete code

Comment: @mave No, LAMP is not an option! didn't know about it! :-)